# Broadcast receiver registered dynamically(via Activity) not working for ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

The broadcast receiver registered for ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED is working fine, but the same is not working for ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED. The thing is that the onReceive() is not called when the intent for ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED is fired.

Here is my code where i register the recievers in onCreate()

```
registerReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED));

    registerReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED));
```

Here is the Code for BroadcastReceiver class:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbDeviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onRecieve", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {


            device = (UsbDevice) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Toast.makeText(
                    SUSB_Serial.this,
                    "ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Log.d("dj", "USB attached");
            connectUsb();


        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {


            try{
                UsbDevice tempDevice = (UsbDevice) intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if(tempDevice != null){

                    if(tempDevice.getProductId() == device.getProductId() 
                            && tempDevice.getVendorId() == device.getVendorId()){

                        Toast.makeText(SUSB_Serial.this,
                                "ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED:",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Log.d("dj", "USB detached");

                        AlertDialog dialog = null;
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SUSB_Serial.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Data reading failed, connect back the devices to continue").setTitle("Device Detached!!").
                        setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });

                        dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                        Log.d("dj", "Releasing resources of USB");
                        releaseUsb();
                    }

                }

            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.d("dj", "Missing device reference");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This so very simple but i forgot to do so...Here is the answer for which the USB_ATTACHED intent-filter not working from Dev docs.

[image]

Also link [USB host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)
Scroll down to the bottom of the page to see the answer